# Find frequencies of multiple words combined as one?

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I am trying to find the frequencies of several words totalled.

For example, I am using this code to find the frequencies of some words

```
keyterms <- c("canadian", "american", "british")
dict <- dictionary(list(keyterms2 = c("canadian", "american", "british"))))


dfm <- dfm(toks) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Organization") %>%
  dfm_select(pattern = keyterms)
```

When I run the above using keyterms and the dictionary, I get the frequencies for each word individually.

| A header | canadian | american | british |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Organization | 10 | 10 | 10 |

Is there a way to write the script so that it returns the frequencies totalled up so that it looks like this:

| A header | terms |
| --- | --- |
| Organization | 30 |

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary approach is the most elegant solution, since it combines your keyword terms.

Here, I've illustrated how you can do this with the built-in inaugural corpus, where your groups (similar to your "Organization") is the president's name.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 3.1
## Unicode version: 13.0
## ICU version: 69.1
## Parallel computing: 12 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.

keyterms <- c("canadian", "american", "british")
dict <- dictionary(list(terms = keyterms))

toks <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
  corpus_subset(Year > 2000) %>%
  tokens() %>%
  tokens_lookup(dictionary = dict)

dfm(toks) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = President) %>%
  convert(to = "data.frame")
##   doc_id terms
## 1  Biden     9
## 2   Bush     6
## 3  Obama     8
## 4  Trump    11
```

(You can rename the first column to "A header" if you wish.)

Note that the usage for `groups` changed in **quanteda** 3.0, so now its value should not be quoted.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Would there be a way to find proportions using the same method? I was playing around with dfm_weight (scheme = prop), but couldn't get it to do as wanted.

Comment: Set `nomatch` in the lookup function, and then use `dfm_weight(x, scheme = "prop")` on the dfm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rowSums` -

```
result <- dfm(toks) %>%
  dfm_group(groups = "Organization")  %>%
  dfm_select(pattern = keyterms) %>%
  rowSums()
```

Using `stack(result)[2:1]` would return a dataframe.